# why we are using tq_struct?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i am new to device driver coding and want to get a clear idea about the struct tq_struct. searched for the documents that explaining well about the structure and its usage, but not get enough documents or reference.

i have the following questions unanswered.

1)why we using tq_struct ?.
2)from where i can get the structure in ubuntu-11.04 ?.
3)how we can use the structure ?.

can anyone help me?. please give some reference and documents.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `struct tq_struct` is a very, *very*  old name for what 2.6 kernels now use `struct work_struct` for.  And that is a data structure defined in `<linux/workqueue.h>` -- it is used with `schedule_work()`, `queue_work()` and so on, to define a unit of work (function pointer plus context value) that should be executed in process context.

Comment: thanks for your help. can you please give some links for reference to explore with the work_struct ?.

Comment: there are gazillions of examples in the kernel source.  also you can look at http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6